# How to restrict the validation only for some elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an xsd with some elements defined in it, an example given below,

```
<xs:complexType name="carType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="vehicleType">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="mode">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element name="off"/>
                                <xs:element name="driving"/>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element ref="speed" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="properties"/>
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="CarA" type="carType" substitutionGroup="vehicleType"/>
<xs:element name="CarB" substitutionGroup="vehicleType"/>
```

I would like to skipe the validation if any xml with elements other than CarA and CarB.

```
<CarC>
    <myCarType/>
</CarC>
```

Currently i am getting 'cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'CarC'.'

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the API that you are using to invoke the schema validator. Look for the option "lax validation". If you use the Saxon s9api interface, you can invoke lax validation by setting `SchemaValidator.setLax(true)`. It's quite possible, of course, that your chosen schema processor does not offer this option.

Lax validation means "if the schema contains a declaration of the relevant element, then validate against that declaration; otherwise treat the content as valid.".